# Python-Dev fails to install on Ubuntu Trusty

Tags: python-2.7, apt-get

I'm trying to install lets-encrypt which led me to python2.7-dev needing to be installed. This however failed with the error below. Any help greatly appreciated:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python2.7-dev : Depends: python2.7 (= 2.7.6-8) but 2.7.6-8ubuntu0.2 is to be installed
                 Depends: libpython2.7-dev (= 2.7.6-8) but 2.7.6-8ubuntu0.2 is to be installed
                 Depends: libpython2.7 (= 2.7.6-8) but 2.7.6-8ubuntu0.2 is to be installed
```

The output from the policy:

```
$ apt-cache policy python2.7
python2.7:
  Installed: 2.7.6-8ubuntu0.2
  Candidate: 2.7.6-8ubuntu0.2
  Version table:
 *** 2.7.6-8ubuntu0.2 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.7.6-8 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 


apt-cache policy python2.7-dev
python2.7-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.7.6-8
  Version table:
     2.7.6-8 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```